# Adding and editing item in datagrid with same controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Hei,

I'm using MVVM with my wpf application. I have DataGrid what shows list of items and i have binded `SelectedItem` to `CurrentSequence` propery in my ViewModel. When `CurrentSequence` changes properties of that object are shown in other controls for editing.

Heres my xaml:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ColorSettingsSequences}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentSequence, Mode=TwoWay}">
    .... more things here ...
</DataGrid>

<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Start temperature (°C)" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="lblSeqStartTemp" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="0,28,10,0" x:Name="tbSeqStartTemp" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentSequence.StartTemp}" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Start color" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="lblSeqHue" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <xctk:ColorPicker Margin="0,28,10,0" x:Name="clrpSeqHue" SelectedColor="{Binding Path=CurrentSequence.StartHue, Converter={StaticResource hueToColor}, ConverterParameter=False}" ShowStandardColors="False" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="End temperature (°C)" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="lblSeqEndTemp" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="0,28,10,0" x:Name="tbSeqEndTemp" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentSequence.EndTemp}" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="End color" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="lblSeqEndHue" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <xctk:ColorPicker Margin="0,28,10,0" x:Name="clrpSeqEndHue" SelectedColor="{Binding Path=CurrentSequence.EndHue, Converter={StaticResource hueToColor}, ConverterParameter=False}" ShowStandardColors="False" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Code:

```
private ColorSettingsSequencesSequence _currentSequence;
public ColorSettingsSequencesSequence CurrentSequence
{
    get
    {
        return this._currentSequence;
    }
    set
    {
        this._currentSequence = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentSequence");
    }
}
```

Now the questions is, how could i add a button what would save changes or add a totally new item. I know how to do one or another, but what about 2 together with same controls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a property on your view model which is of type ColorSettingsSequencesSequence named CurrentSequenceEdit and you can set the value of this object upon changing selection.

Then upon click of an add button you can create a new ColorSettingsSequencesSequence object and set it to the value of CurrentSequenceEdit.

Typically on a new object you'll have an ID that is not set or is set to a negative number which you can use in the Save command to determine whether it needs added to the grid or not.

Comment: Ahh, i wonder how i couldn't think about this myself. Actually i know, i was thinking that i would press "Add new" button after i have entered the new values to controls..